# How do you assign individual .hover with same code jquery

Tags: jquery

I have create the following slideup effect using jquery - but I want it to work once on each hover.

```
 // Get a reference to the container.
            var container = $( ".container" );
            // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
            $("a.hover-btn" ).hover(
                function( e ){
                    // Prevent the default event.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // Toggle the slide based on its current
                    // visibility.
                    if (container.is( ":visible" )){

                        // Hide - slide up.
                        container.slideUp( 200 );
                        $('a.hover-btn').addClass('off');
                        $('a.hover-btn').removeClass('on');

                    } else {

                        // Show - slide down.
                        container.slideDown( 200 );
                        $('a.hover-btn').addClass('on');
                        $('a.hover-btn').removeClass('off');

                    }
                }
            );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/XtBPQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.siblings()` to get desired container:

```
// Bind the link to toggle the slide.
$("a.hover-btn").hover(

function (e) {
    // Prevent the default event.
    e.preventDefault();
    // Toggle the slide based on its current
    // visibility.
    // Get a reference to the container.
    var container = $(this).siblings(".container");
    if (container.is(":visible")) {

        // Hide - slide up.
        container.slideUp(200);
        $('a.hover-btn').addClass('off');
        $('a.hover-btn').removeClass('on');

    } else {

        // Show - slide down.
        container.slideDown(200);
        $('a.hover-btn').addClass('on');
        $('a.hover-btn').removeClass('off');

    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XtBPQ/2/

But I would recommened to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, better to control that way:

```
// Bind the link to toggle the slide.
$("a.hover-btn").on('mouseenter', function () {
    var $btn = $(this);

    // Get a reference to the container.
    var $container = $btn.siblings(".container");

    $container.slideDown(200);
    $btn.addClass('on');
    $btn.removeClass('off');
})
.on('mouseleave', function () {
    var $btn = $(this);

    // Get a reference to the container.
    var $container = $btn.siblings(".container");

    // Hide - slide up.
    $container.slideUp(200);
    $btn.addClass('off');
    $btn.removeClass('on');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XtBPQ/6/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, as you can't unbind the equal jQuery function itself (as far as I know):

```
$('a.hover-btn').unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
```

What this does is practically unbind the native bindings (listeners) jQuery put on the tags.

For some browsers the above works better, for some this code works better:

```
$('a.hover-btn').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Try what works best for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the parent div and then find the .container..

```
// Get a reference to the container.

// Bind the link to toggle the slide.
$("a.hover-btn" ).hover(
    function( e ){
        // Prevent the default event.
        e.preventDefault();
        // Toggle the slide based on its current
        // visibility.
        var current_container = $(this).parent('.sliderContent').children('.container');
        if (current_container.is( ":visible" )){

            // Hide - slide up.
           current_container.slideUp( 200 );
            $(this).addClass('off');
            $(this).removeClass('on');

        } else {

            // Show - slide down.
            current_container.slideDown( 200 );
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $(this).removeClass('off');

        }
    }
);
```

Or instead of

`var current_container = $(this).parent('.sliderContent').children('.container');`

you could do what the other poster done

`var current_container = $(this).siblings(".container");`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/XtBPQ/4/

Answer (score 0):

**edit** O im to late xD

```
$("a.hover-btn").hover(

function (e) {
    // Prevent the default event.
    e.preventDefault();
    // Toggle the slide based on its current
    // visibility.
    // Get a reference to the container.
    var container = $(this).siblings(".container");
    if (container.is(":visible")) {

        // Hide - slide up.
        container.slideUp(200);
        $('a.hover-btn').addClass('off');
        $('a.hover-btn').removeClass('on');

    } else {

        // Show - slide down.
        container.slideDown(200);
        $('a.hover-btn').addClass('on');
        $('a.hover-btn').removeClass('off');

    }
});
```

you did tell to Jquery that the var container is alle with the class container, all containers.
Make with var container = $(this).siblings(".container"); that you only select the container match your div hover.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this is something you want to achieve:

```
$("a.hover-btn").hover(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('on').slideDown(200);
   $(this).addClass('on');
}, function () {
   $(this).removeClass('on').siblings().slideUp(200);
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XtBPQ/7/)

However in terms of performance you can cache the object:

```
var $this = $(this);
$("a.hover-btn").hover(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $this.siblings().removeClass('on').slideDown(200);
   $this.addClass('on');
}, function () {
   $this.removeClass('on').siblings().slideUp(200);
});
```